# SASS is converting "at top right" to "right top" in my radial-gradient

Tags: css, sass, gradient

I am currently using the following property in CSS:

```
background: radial-gradient(at top right, rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
```

If I try this property in my browser, it works fine, though when I put it in my sass file, it is somehow converted to css incorrectly.

```
background: radial-gradient(right top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
```

at top right is converted to right top.

Anything I could do to prevent this ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it should work - http://sassmeister.com/gist/6369ff61db457fd9fc83 . You could always omit the `at`...what happens if you do?

Comment: Same, the top right becomes right top and then fails.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea unless you are using variables and have somehow confused them.

Comment: Sass does no such thing, but you're not using vanilla Sass, are you?

Comment: Have you updated compass in a while?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the output you're seeing with either Compass 1.0.3 (current stable version) or 1.1.0 Alpha 3.