# Compass/SCSS compiling rewrites css rules to opposite direction

Tags: css, sass, compass

I am using Compass to compile SCSS and when the following rule is compiled:

```
// foo.scss
div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #cccccc 0%, #eeeeee 60%);
}
```

It translates into the following CSS rule:

```
// foo.css
div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cccccc 0%, #eeeeee 60%);
}
```

Notice how it translated `left` into `to right` . I am aware the that definition I am supplying is not the right format, it should be:

```
// foo.scss
div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cccccc 0%, #eeeeee 60%);
}
```

I am in the process of correcting the rule but wanted to have some understanding of why this happens and why it happens so silently.

- Can someone point me to some documentation that will tell me why this is happening?
- Also, is it possible to have compass warn me about this so that I can be aware that it is rewriting my rules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS is converting "at top right" to "right top" in my radial-gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632751/sass-is-converting-at-top-right-to-right-top-in-my-radial-gradient)

Comment: The value of 'left' under the old gradient syntax is identical to the 'to right' value under the standardized syntax.  There is no "opposite direction" going on here.

Answer (score -1):

One definition is according to the old syntax, and the other according to the new syntax, but both are equivalent.

See, for instance [this](http://www.broken-links.com/2012/01/11/the-new-and-hopefully-final-linear-gradient-syntax/)

or [this](http://codetheory.in/the-new-and-final-css3-linear-and-radial-gradients-syntax/)

quote from the later

> Now, take a look at the old/new versions of some sample codez:
>
> /* Old */
>   background-image: linear-gradient(top, red, green);
>
> /* New */
>   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, green);
>
> /* Old */
>   background-image: linear-gradient(left, red, green);
>
> /* New */
>   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
>
> /* Old */
>   background-image: linear-gradient(bottom left, red, green);
>
> /* New */
>   background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red, green);
>
> /* Old */
>   background-image: linear-gradient(top left, red, green);
>
> /* New */
>   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, green);

Comment: Does not answer the question.  While the OP appears to be ignorant of the changes to the gradient syntax, it does not explain why the gradient is being rewritten.

Comment: @cimmanon it isn't being rewritten, it's being converted to the new syntax

Comment: Same difference.  Again, you're not answering the question.  You're only explaining the difference between the old and new syntax, something the question I marked this a duplicate of *does*.